# Dict of cluster and partition with kmeans python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, k-means

I search a solution to my problem.

I use Kmeans by sklearn and i want a dictionary with `{ cluster : list of partition}`

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n)
kmeans.fit(data)

result = zip(data,kmeans.labels_)
sortedR = sorted(result,key=lambda x: x[1])

cluster_nb = {}
for k,v in sortedR:
    if v in cluster_nb:
        cluster_nb[v].append(k)
    else:
        cluster_nb[v] = [k]
```

I have the positions of the clusters of kmoyen.labels as key but I need a corresponding element of kmoyen.cluster_centers_

For example :

```
{'[1,2]' :  [array([1, 3]), array([2,4])], '[5,5]' : [array([7, 8]), array([10,12])]}
```

I tried with a new loop :

```
for x in cluster_nb:
    cluster_nb[str(kmeans.cluster_centers_[x])] = cluster_nb.pop(x)
return cluster_nb
```

But i have this error :

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Where am I making my error?

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: To be sure: you are trying to retrieve, for each cluster the partiton of the input data belonging to that cluster?

Comment: Yes, with the partition cluster coordinate as key

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 2))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
kmeans.fit(data)

centroids_partitions = {}
for centr in kmeans.cluster_centers_:
    centroid_label = kmeans.predict([centr])
    partition = []
    for k, v in zip(data, kmeans.labels_):
        if v == centroid_label:
            partition.append(k.ravel())

    centroids_partitions[centroid_label[0]] = partition

print(centroids_partitions)
```

That returns a dict like:

```
{0: [array([55,  8]), ... ,[truncated], 1: [array([70, 87]), array([77, 63]), ... ]}
```

Where 0, 1, etc are the clusters labels from `kmeans.labels_`

Or, if you want to have the centroids coordinated as key for the dict, replace with:

```
centroids_partitions[centr[0],centr[1]] = partition
```

That outputs:

```
{(68.29411764705881, 24.470588235294127): [array([72, 19]), array([69,  1]), array([58, 46]), .... ]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That's exactly what I wanted
Have a nice day